# golang interfaces for testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface, mocking

I am trying to create a database mock in my code, then i am introducing interfaces to my code, to create the mock:

This is my code (I don't know if it's the correct approach)

```
package interfaces

type ObjectAPI interface {
    FindSomethingInDatabase(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error)
}
```

And my implementation of the interface is:

```
package repositories

func FindSomethingInDatabase(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error) {

    statement, err := db.SqlStatementWithCtx(ctx,
        `SELECT * 
         FROM table
         WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1`)

    row := statement.QueryRowContext(ctx, name)

    if err != nil {
        return e.Response{}, err
    }

    statement.Close()
    return toResponse(row), nil  //this method convert row database to e.Response struct

}
```

Now I need call from one method the implementation of my FindSomethingInDatabase, then i am receiving an object type interface:

```
func CallImplementation(request *dto.XRequest, repo i.ObjectAPI) dto.XResponse{
    result := repo.FindSomethingInDatabase(request.Ctx, request.Name)
// more code
}
```

But now I don't know how can I call  `CallImplementation``  to pass an object with the implementation.

Call the method passing the implementation of the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface describes a *type*. Since your `FindSomethingInDatabase` implementation is just a func without a receiver, there is no type that implements interface `ObjectAPI`.

You can pass a value of type `func(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error)` into `CallImplementation` as a callback and get rid of the interface altogether. Alternatively, keep the interface, define a type, and make that type the receiver for your current `FindSomethingInDatabase` implementation. You can then pass the type to `CallImplementation`, since it will now implement the `ObjectAPI` interface. An example of the latter (which would be my preferred option for extensibility):

```golang
type database struct {}

func (d *database) FindSomethingInDatabase(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error) {
    // ...
}

func CallImplementation(request *dto.XRequest, repo i.ObjectAPI) dto.XResponse{
    result := repo.FindSomethingInDatabase(request.Ctx, request.Name)
// more code
}

func main() {
    db := &database{}
    _ = Callimplementation(getRequest(), db)
}
```

In this case, you will probably want to store `db` as a member of `database`, rather than having it as a global variable (which appears to be the case now).

Comment: I don't understand here, how can i implement other FindSomethingInDatabase2 for example, returning a dummy   (e.Response, error), and call it after

Comment: @daocc You wouldn't implement a `FindSomethingInDatabase2`, but _another_ `FindSomethingInDatabase`. But you'd define it with a different receiver type. For example, you'd have a `database` type (like in my example), and then a `mockDatabase` one. Both have a `FindSomethingInDatabase` method, and you can freely pass either into `CallImplementation` (i.e. the mock when testing, and the real thing otherwise)

Comment: And is strange that If I need mock for example 3 methods, I need receive in my CallImplementation function, more parameters, then I need receive a parameter per mock

Answer (score 0):

refer [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery). it provides auto generation of mocks for interfaces and can be good reference about best practices for mocking.

typically you would do this:

api.go:

```golang
type API interface {
    Something(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error)
}

type ApiImpl struct {
  
}

func (t *ApiImpl) Something(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error) {
    // impl
}
```

api_test.go

```golang
// mocks can be hand coded or autogenerated using mockery
type MockImpl struct {
}

func (m *MockImpl) Something(ctx context.Context, name string) (e.Response, error) {
    // mock implementation
}

func TestSomething(t * testing.T) {
    // test code with mocks
}
```